# UIProgressView in CustomCell never show when NSNotification was sent

Tags: ios, multithreading, uitableview, nsnotifications, uiprogressview

I've got magazine app. There is `UITableView` which contains custom cells. In each cell is button, icon, title and hidden `UIProgressView`. When someone tap to button, pages (images) are starting to download. When some page is downloaded, I want to show hidden `UIProgressView` or update. And there's the problem. I'm using `NSNotification` and `performSelectorOnMainThread` for updating `UIProgressView`. But the `UIProgressView` doesn't show. I don't know where error is... Thx for reply!

There's some code...
Creating `UIProgressView`:

```
self.progressView = [[UIProgressView alloc] initWithProgressViewStyle:UIProgressViewStyleBar];
[self.progressView setFrame:CGRectMake(250, 200, 92, 28)];
[self.progressView setProgress:0.0];
[self.progressView setHidden:YES];
[self.cellView addSubview:self.progressView];
```

Posting notificaiton:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kDownloadedIcon object:nil userInfo:dict];
```

Accepting notification:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(iconDownloaded:) name:kDownloadedIcon object:nil];
```

Resend notification to main thread:

```
- (void)iconDownloaded:(NSNotification *)notification {
[self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateProgressBar:) withObject:notification waitUntilDone:YES];}
```

Update or show `UIProgressView`:

```
- (void)updateProgressBar:(NSNotification *)notification {
NSDictionary *dict = [notification userInfo];

NSLog(@"%@ %@ %@", [dict objectForKey:@"name"], self.identifier, self.progressView);

if ([[dict objectForKey:@"name"] isEqualToString:self.identifier]) {
    if (self.spinner) [spinner stopAnimating];
    self.spinner = nil;
    [self.spinner removeFromSuperview];

    [self.progressView setHidden:NO];
    self.progress++;
    NSInteger count = [[dict objectForKey:@"pages"] intValue];
    [self.progressView setProgress:self.progress/count];
}
```

Comment: Does your `NSLog` inside `-updateProgressBar:` show up in the console?

Comment: Yes, console wrote everythings fine.

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint right before you call `[self.progressView setHidden:NO]`? Check to see what `self.progressView` is (make sure it's not `nil`), look at its frame, its superview, etc.

Comment: Try it. `self.progressView` is never nil. Could it be any problem with drawing?

Comment: Can you update your post with the names of the classes that have each of the code snippets you posted? For example, what class creates the UIProgressView?

Comment: A sample project works for me. In addition to the class information, can you look at the frame of your progress view and the frame of your `cellView`? It's possible you're placing your progress view outside your cell's visible area and just not noticing right away since you set it hidden.

Comment: Thx for interest Tim. Progress view is in cell, I try it display before I hide it. UIProgressView is created when I'm creating cellView. So I create progress view in my `CustomCell : UITableViewCell`. Could u give me the sample project which you've created?

Comment: See [this project](https://github.com/lithium3141/SO-ProgressViewTest) on GitHub.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hurray! Thx Tim for ideas! Your "simple project" helped me to solved it. Problem was, I start for loop. In this loop I'm posting notifications. But when for starts, it blocks main thread and UI hasn't been redrawn. So I sent calling of for loop to background and everything works fine. Thx again Tim